# Read file data for android

Tags: android, android-file

I have got some trouble with reading a file. I read the file from `onCreate`, but if I change the text on the next page it saves but I don't see the new data.

I save in file in `onPause`, `onSaveInstance`, but if I restart the application it's ok. But I don't know why only that.
When I must read file?

Comment: from what I know from your question; read file in onActivtyResult()... Provide more information. Some example of code.

Comment: Please **learn** the activity life cycle.  `onResume()` is called whether your activity is a new instance or is reloaded.

Comment: vrstica je reku.. you should save your stuff in onPause or onSaveInstance

Comment: jap hvala ti sem poštuderu dela zdej, thanks ...:P i copy code on right part of android cycle, thanks all..

Comment: Paste previous code back on your post so also others with similar issue will see the problem and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow below steps:

1. use startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
2. goto next page(activity) change file and save file also
3. then use 
   Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
   //intent.putExtra("SOMETHING", "EXTRAS");
   (if file changes) setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); else setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);(if file did not change)
   finish();

Answer (score 0):

Save your stuff in `onPause()` or `onSaveInstance()`